# Multi-language dictation in Catalina

Tags: catalina, voice-dictation

Catalina [took away my ability to dictate in more than one language](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375011/will-catalina-always-do-dictation-online-when-possible).

Is there a way to restore that?

Comment: A minor irritation is that once it is turned on, it can't be turned off without opening system preferences.  The little control box sits there all the time with a sleep or awake instead of the "done" it used to have.  And the fn-fn no longer affects it.